# Selenium: to simulate a click on Chrome toolbar

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to simulate a click on Chrome toolbar using Selenium?

Specifically, I want to click on the button [Stop loading this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izZpT.png) ("X" shaped) while the page is loading. This is to prevent the page from infinite loading.

*I know we have methods for the other three buttons.*

```
driver.navigate().refresh(); 
driver.navigate().back(); 
driver.navigate().forward();
```

Comment: in which programming language? If your aim is to prevent infinite loading - what did you try so far (maybe Wait ? Pressing keyboard shortcut ?)

Comment: Have you looked at this https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/is-it-possible-to-stop-page-loading-on-the-browser-using-selenium-web-driver

Comment: @SmartDumb WebDriverWait and keyboard shortcut cannot do the trick because they both require driver instance returned from a full page load.

Comment: @HaC I am not sure why JavascriptExecutor would work because when I am using "driver.get(url)" for example, if the page is not fully loaded then code will be stuck there and no chance to execute "return window.stop”

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent infinite loading you should use below line of code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If a website does not load in required time, the `TimeoutException` will be thrown. 
`org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for page load.`

It is not easy to press `stop` button in the browser. Why?

If you perform `get` operation and you want to stop the browser, selenium will not perform any other method, unless method `get` is finished or threw a timeout. You would have to separate threads, do a concurrent run. 2 Threads would have to work on the same instance of the browser. That's why it's better to set the timeout.

When the timeout is thrown, you can catch it to continue the execution.

```
try {
    driver.get("my url");
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaintion. The problem here is if I want to click some link and be navigated to a new page, then I'll have to write a nested try-catch-finally and if there're lots of links to go thru this could be really tricky

Comment: Could you explain more what are you trying to do? What is your expected outcome? You have a list of links. You want to iterate through this list and click each link separately?